# как узнать путь до папки?

Tags: java

У меня есть программа, мне не важно где она лежит или откуда запущена, мне важно достать файлы из другой папки.

Допустим на компьютере есть папка Program "C:\Users\User\AppData\Program"
как мне узнать её расположение при том что диск может быть не "С"(у меня к примеру D) а "User" точно будет называться по другому?

Answer (score 1):

Метод "System.getProperty" с ключем "user.home" возвращает дирикторию пользователя 
то-есть "C:\Users\User".

Можно сделать так:
String dir=System.getProperty("user.home");

Также есть и другие ключи про которые можно прочитать на доках оракла:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html